# Existe algum adjetivo correspondente a «cedo»?

Tags: palavra-para-ideia, adjetivos

Em particular, eu procuro uma palavra para um tipo de frase que eu emprego frequentemente em respostas a perguntas de etimologia:

> A ocorrência de *Thiago* mais _________ que eu encontrei é de tal e tal ano na obra tal e tal.

Já considerei várias possibilidades, mas não me satisfazem completamente. Na frase acima eu posso dizer *a ocorrência mais antiga*, que é o que eu tenho feito. Mas *mais antiga* qualifica a ocorrência relativamente ao momento atual — a ocorrência com mais idade — e eu gostaria de um adjetivo que a qualificasse relativamente à origem da língua — a ocorrência que surge primeiro.

Em muitos contextos, eu poderia simplesmente dizer *a primeira ocorrência*. Mas não naquela frase. Eu não posso ter a presunção de ter encontrado a primeira ocorrência, e tenho de qualificar com *que eu encontrei*. Ora *a primeira ocorrência que eu encontrei* é em rigor a ocorrência que eu encontrei antes de ter encontrado as outras; não a que ocorre antes das outras.

Poderia talvez dizer *a primeira ocorrência entre as que encontrei*, mas parece-me que fica menos claro e imediato. Se não houver opção melhor, acho que me ficava pela *ocorrência mais antiga*.

*A primeira ocorrência de que tenho conhecimento* — em vez de *que eu encontrei* —  parece-me que funciona, mas não transmite a ideia de que eu andei agora aturadamente à procura.

Um adjetivo correspondente, etimologicamente ou não, a *cedo*, resolvia-me os problemas todos. Em inglês, eu escreveria ali [*earliest* (Oxford)](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/early_1?q=early), mas não consegui encontrar nada em português que servisse. Existe alguma palavra?

Tal palavra poderia naturalmente ter outros usos. Exemplos:

> Esta igreja é um exemplo _________ do barroco no Brasil [parafraseável em *esta igreja é um dos primeiros exemplos do barroco no Brasil*]
>
> O novo achado arqueológico é o povoamento humano mais _________ descoberto até hoje no continente americano

Comment: "prematuro"?  "precoce"?  "primitivo"?   Prefiro mesmo mais antigo.

Comment: Concordo com o @Centaurus.

Comment: Isto parecem-me duas perguntas diferentes. O exemplo da igreja pede _prematuro_ / _precoce_ (antes do tempo habitual); é um antónimo de _tardio_. Mas a primeira frase e a última pedem _antigo_ (recuado no tempo, independentemente da ideia de vir antes do tempo normal/habitual).  Em inglês poderia usar-se _early_ / _earliest_ para os dois significados, mas isso é em inglês.

Comment: @Artefacto Eu quero que a frase da igreja tenha o mesmo significado que *esta igreja é um dos primeiros exemplos*, independentemente de ser precoce ou não. Começo a pensar é que *antónimo de tardio* não descreve o que eu pretendo: nos dicionários que vi, *tardio* vem apenas como 'depois do tempo normal'

Comment: @Centaurus Parece-me que *prematuro* e *precoce* ('vem, desenvolve-se antes do tempo normal ou apropriado) não servem para o que eu quero. Fiquei a pensar no *primitivo*...

Comment: o que você quer é primordial

Comment: @AndréLyra Também ja me lembrei de *primordial*. Mas creio que nunca vi ou ouvi *o mais primordial*.

Comment: primordial já indica que é o mais, não se usa o mais primordial, usa-se apenas primordial "A ocorrência primordial de Thiago que eu encontrei é..."

Comment: @AndréLyra Mas isso não é o que eu quero dizer: a frase tem de ficar equivalente a *a ocorrência mais antiga que eu encontrei*. Ora a ocorrência mais antiga que eu encontrei pode não ser primordial: a mais antiga que eu encontro pode ser, por exemplo, de 1700, mas se existirem ocorrências de 1300 (que eu não encontrei), a que eu encontrei de 1700 não é primordial.

Comment: Quando você escreve "que eu encontrei é", ou melhor ainda, "encontrada", já fica claro que você não sabe se existem anteriores ou não pode encontrar nada mais longe no tempo. Não significa necessariamente que é a palavra original.

Comment: Se estás convencido disso escreve uma resposta. Mas para mim isso não é verdade: primordial tem um sentido absoluto, independente de eu o encontrar ou não.

Comment: Poderia ser "A ocorrência primária de Thiago que encontrei é tal", "A ocorrência primeira / primordial de Thiago que encontrei é tal". "A ocorrência mais originária de Thiago que encontrei é tal", "A ocorrência de Thiago mais anterior que encontrei é tal"

Answer (score 2):

"Precoce" seria a palavra indicada, embora tenha a conotação de algo que acontece antes do tempo "certo". Talvez "temprano" apesar do sabor arcaizante e de ser espanholismo (a forma propriamente portuguesa temporã(o) soa coloquial demais). Ou podes talvez usar "recuado/a": *A ocorrência mais recuada que encontrei*.

Comment: *Precoce* significa simplesmente 'que se desenvolve antes do tempo normal'; isso não se aplica aos meu exemplos. Não encontrei *temprano* em dicionário nenhum. Tens exemplos de uso? Na verdade eu já usei *temporão* numa resposta qualquer (tou-me nas tintas para se é coloquial ou não), depois consultei o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/tempor%C3%A3o) e fiquei com dúvidas. Parece-me que *recuado* não melhora relativamente a *antigo*.

Comment: Bom, talvez seja minha formação acadêmica, mas para mim o oposto de capitalismo tardio é capitalismo precoce. Mas concordo que não dá para aplicar em todas as situações. E o temprano talvez tenha a ver com o meu Rio Grande do Sul natal (em todo caso, nestes tempos em que estamos a importar tantas palavras inglesas, algumas delas bem desnecessárias, acho que a importação desta palavra castelhana não de todo inútil seria talvez um mal menor).

Comment: Eu compreendo *capitalismo precoce*, mas no uso que quero fazer (que espero que esteja claro na pergunta) não quero dar a ideia que a palavra ocorre antes do seu 'tempo normal'. Também não tenho objeções a importações do espanhol, mas não conheço o uso: tens exemplos de uso em situações do tipo dos meus exemplos? Por outro lado ainda não desisti do *temporão*: já o vi definido em dicionários antigos apenas como 'que vem antes dos outros', que é como eu me lembro (vagamente) de o ouvir empregar.

Comment: @Jacinto - "Temporão", pelo menos no Brasil, adquiriu um sentido paradoxal; diz-se "temporão" o filho mais novo, nascido com grande intervalo depois do penúltimo ("Não é o meu neto, é o meu filho temporão").

Comment: A mim parece que estamos diante de um caso em que não há uso consagrado, e as alternativas existentes não transmitem a ideia precisa de que necessitamos. É caso portanto para neologismo ou importação, ou para a ressurreição de arcaísmos. Adiante, pois, e às favas os puristas e seus escrúpulos! Ressuscitemos o "temporão" ou importemos o "temprano", e o uso, se for o caso, consagrará a ousadia. (E, não, não tenho exemplo de uso de "temprano" na linguagem escrita; às vezes uso a palavra, coloquialmente, na comunicação oral, mas pode ser só o meu idioleto).

Comment: Única das opções possíveis que diz o que se quer dizer é "recuada" e mesmo assim com uma elipse de "no tempo" tendo de passar pela cabeça do leitor. "recuada no tempo"

Comment: Ao invés de precoce use então prematura.